# How can I edit a git branch's description programmatically?

Tags: git

I'd like to automatically set the description of a git branch using a bash function or something similar.

With `git`, it is possible to edit the description of a branch as follows:

```
git branch --edit-description
```

However, this opens a vim editor for modifying the description, which I would have to manually edit and then close out of, preventing me from automating the process.

Does anyone know of a way to do this programmatically, either using some sort of `git` command I'm unaware of or somehow piping input to the vim somehow?

Comment: Technically, you can use `git branch --edit` to do what you want, by setting the editor to be a program that produces the description you want (e.g., `GIT_EDITOR=script git branch --edit-description`). However, your own answer of using `git config` is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I've figured it out. It's a simple git config value, so setting the description is as easy as:

```
git config branch.<branch_name>.description "Enter description here"
```

Comment: Should be only in local config, or it will also impact other repos. But your command is fine, since `--local` is implied by default.